# namespaced rails route finds correct controller in console but not live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

super stumped right now - running rails 3.2.17

I have a path helper:

```
partner_documents_partner_documents_path
```

which correctly generates this path:

```
/en/partner/documents/partner_documents
```

which, according to my console is recognized and correctly mapped to the desired controller action:

```
   [12] »  r = Rails.application.routes
    => #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fb828169a58>
   [13] » r.recognize_path("en/partner/documents/partner_documents")
    => {
    :action => "partner_documents",
    :controller => "project/partner/documents",
    :locale => "en"
    }
```

However, in my browser, when attempting to navigate to that path (expecting the above controller action to do it's thing), I'm presented with a *different* controller, one that does not have the action defined (and rightly so).

This is the error I receive:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /en/partner/documents/partner_documents
The action 'partner_documents' could not be found for Project::DocumentsController
```

The controller it *should* be hitting, the one located at the path above (`project/partner/documents`) is `Project::Partner::DocumentsController`, *not* `Project::DocumentsController`.

At first I thought maybe something was off between the environment in my console and my local server -- but that doesn't appear to be the case. Also, the request parameters displayed on the error page even *show* the correct controller path:

```
Request parameters  
{
 "action"=>"partner_documents", 
 "controller"=>"project/partner/documents", 
 "locale"=>"en"
}
```

this is the relevant entry in `routes.rb`:

```
scope '/:locale', :module => :project do
...
  namespace :partner do
  ...
  resources :documents do
    collection do
      get :partner_documents
      ...
```

What is going on here??

Comment: Can you run this command - "rake routes" and post the output ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder using 'show-routes' in the console gives me this relevant line:  '                            partner_documents_partner_documents GET    /:locale/partner/documents/partner_documents(.:format)                             finance_it/partner/documents#partner_documents'

Comment: Can you post it as code in question to improve readability ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder yes sorry I totally should have. However I've just solved the issue. thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The issue stemmed from an improper include. I'm not sure why I wasn't getting an "uninitialized constant" error instead of having it redirect to another controller, but in the controller I was trying to hit I had this:

```
class Project::Partner::DocumentsController < Project::PartnerController
  include EsignatureHelper
```

where what I needed to have was this:

```
class Project::Partner::DocumentsController < Project::PartnerController
  include Esignatures::EsignatureHelper
```